# How should I reference grandparent properties in a GraphQL query, where I don't define the intermediate resolver?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I am building a GraphQL Schema that has a Type Pod which contains 3 nested objects.

```
type Pod { 
  metadata: Metadata 
  spec: Spec 
  status: Status
}
```

My data source is an external API which returns an array of this data. In fact, I defined my schema around this API response. I have included a trimmed down version below.

```
[ 
   {
      "metadata": {
          "name": "my-app-65",
          "namespace": "default",
      },
      "spec": {
          "containers": [
              {
                  "name": "hello-world",
                  "image": "container-image.io/unique-id",

              }
          ],
  
  },
  // more like-objects in the array
]
```

However, for each of these container objects, inside the array. I would like to add some extra information which this initial API call does not provide. However, I can query this information separately if I provide the name & namespace properties on the parent's metadata.

`/container/endpoint/${namespace}/${name}`

Returns...

```
[ {
  name: "hello-world",
  nestObj: { 
    //data 
  } 
 },
]
```

And I would like to add this nested Obj to the original space when that data is queried.

However, I don't have a clean way to access the pod.metadata.name inside the resolver for Container.

Currently my resolvers look like....

```
Query: {
  pods: async () => {
    //query that returns array of pod objects
    return pods
  }
},
Container: {
  name: "hello-world",
  nestedObj: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
    //query that hits the second endpoint but requires name & namespace.
    //however, I don't have access to those values.
  }
}
```

**Perfect world solution:** I could access parent.parent.metadata.name inside the Container Resolver

**Current Approach (brute force, repetitively add the property to the children)**
Loop through every nested container objs in every Pod and add the podName & namespace as properties there.

```
pods.forEach(pod => pod.spec.containers.forEach(container => {
        container.podName = pod.metadata.name;
        container.namespace = pod.metadata.namespace;
      }))
```

This feels very much like a hack, and really bogs down my query times. Especially considering this data won't always be requested.

I have two intuitive ideas but don't know how to implement them (I'm a bit new to graphQL).

1. Implement a Pod resolver that would then pass this data in through the rootValue as described here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1098
2. Access it somewhere inside the info object

The problem the first one, is that my data source only sends me the data as an array, not individual pods and I'm unsure how to pass that array of data into resolvers for individual components.

The problem with second, is that object is very dense. I tried accessing it via the path. But path seems to only store the type, not the actual data.

It's also possible I'm just implementing this completely wrong and welcome such feedback.

Thanks for any guidance, suggestions, or resources.

Comment: `pods.forEach(pod => pod.spec.containers.forEach(container => { container.pod = pod; }))` ? (or `container.meta=pod.metadata`) you don't need intermediate parents (no resolvers in the middle) ... but are you sure about nested call args (namespace ok, but name from meta, not from container)? it looks like all nested will have the same data (duplication, can be resolved at pod level)

Comment: @xadm are you suggesting that I nest the entire pod or pod.metadata structure inside each container? 

I suppose I could do that, but I'm not sure it would change very much as I still need to loop through every container in every pod and append a new property. 

Is the time complexity of such a solution any better? I imagine it would take up more space in memory; but that's fine if execution is improved.

Comment: it's only a reference ... having one `pod` you can access meta fields [in nested resolver] by `parent.pod.metadata.name` and `parent.pod.metadata.namespace`